# Assign an object to a Map, where the Map is defined using type parameters from the parent class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I'm building a two-way mapping class that I want to construct using an object:

```
class TwoWayMap<K extends string|number, V extends string|number> {
    private map: Map<K, V>;
    private reverseMap: Map<V, K>;
    constructor(obj: { [key in K]: V }) {
        this.map = new Map(Object.entries(obj)); //Error occurs here
        this.reverseMap = new Map<V, K>();
        for (let [key, val] of this.map) {
            this.reverseMap.set(val, key);
        }
    }
    public get(key: K): V | undefined { return this.getFromKey(key); }
    public getFromKey(key: K): V | undefined { return this.map.get(key); }
    public getFromVal(val: V): K | undefined { return this.reverseMap.get(val); }
}
```

Intended usage:

```
let myMap = new TwoWayMap<string, number>({
    'a' : 1,
    'b' : 2,
    ....
});
console.log(myMap.getFromKey('a'));  //Returns 1
console.log(myMap.getFromVal(2));    //Returns 'b'
```

At the marked point in the class definition, though, I get an error that seems to indicate Typescript is assuming the object keys are strings (apologies, I don't have access to the environment at the moment; I'll update with the precise error message when able). `map`'s keys and the input object's keys are both defined using the type parameter K, so I'm not sure why it fails. I guess I'm failing to narrow the key's type correctly? What's going on here?

**Edit:** The error code:

```
Type 'Map<string, V>' is not assignable to type 'Map<K, V>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'K'.
    'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number'. typescript(2322)
```

Comment: `Object.entries` returns **string** keys.

Comment: ① The issue here is indeed that `Object.entries()` isn't known to return only the entries TypeScript knows about, so there might be more keys than just `K`.  See the linked question/answer for more information.  If you're sure it's safe then use a type assertion and move on.

Comment: ② Beware, your code has a problem unrelated to what you're asking: objects in JavaScript don't really have `number` keys, and TypeScript only *pretends* that they do.  If you get `Object.entries({0: 1})` you'll get `[["0",1]]`, not `[[0,1]]`.  So you need to replace `K` with `\`${K}\`` if you want to accurately represent what will happen at runtime.

Comment: Oof, good to know. Honestly, at that point it sounds like I'd be better off forgoing type parameters entirely and just specify all keys and values as strings. Yes?